# $( "#hover"+item ) does not work but $( "#hover0" ) works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code as follow:

```
$( "#hover0" )
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $( "#hover0" ).attr("style","background-color:#e1e8ed;");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $( "#hover0" ).removeAttr();
    });
```

which works perfectly but as soon as I change it to the following it does not work:

```
var item=0;
$( "#hover"+item )
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $( "#hover"+item  ).attr("style","background-color:#e1e8ed;");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $( "#hover"+item  ).removeAttr();
    });
```

what is the problem?Can anyone help me how I can do it like the second approach?(Actually the real scenario is a for loop with item changing as each loop passes)

Update:

Here is my loop:

```
for (var item in jsresult) {

    if (jsresult[item] != "null") {

    $('#tweetWrapper')
        .append("<div class='tweetCon' id='hover"+item+"' >" +
                "<div class='tweetimgcon' ><img alt='' height='50px' src='"+jsresult[item].url+"'></div>" +
                "<div class='tweetcontitle' >"+jsresult[item].name+"</div>" +
                "<div class='tweetcondate' >"+jsresult[item].date+"</div>" +
                "<div class='tweetconcontent' '>"+jsresult[item].text+"</div>" +
                "</div><div class='ttest' style='float:left;height:300px;width:100%;display:none;'></div>");

    $("#hover0")
      .mouseenter(function() {
        $( "#hover0" ).attr("style","background-color:#e1e8ed;");
      })
      .mouseleave(function() {
        $( "#hover0" ).removeAttr();
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: `the real scenario is a for loop` <- and therein lies the problem, it's not the number that is the issue, it's the loop.

Comment: Why the loop cause trouble?

Comment: BTW: dont use `style` Directly, use `css()`  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @meni181818 Thanks but if it was the style proble it should not have worked with $( "#hover0" )

Comment: What is `jsresult`? How does it look like?

Comment: it is a returned json which works properly

Comment: FYI: You should also not have quotes around null. You are checking for the string "null" rather than a null value.

Comment: How does it not work? What results are you seeing? I'd recommend logging `item` to the console to see if you are getting what you expect.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle and/or json that is returned?

Comment: See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those handlers will always use the last-known value of `item`, not the value that it had when you set them up.

Better to move the handler code into a setup function, and call that - its local variable will always have the right value.

```
function addHandlers(item) {
  $( "#hover"+item )
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $( "#hover"+item  ).attr("style","background-color:#e1e8ed;");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $( "#hover"+item  ).removeAttr('style');
    });
}

// called as...
//
for(var item in jsresult)
{     
  if (jsresult[item]!="null")
  {
    // wrappers, etc., then...
    //

    addHandlers( item );
  }
}
```